# Count number of non-overlapping intervals

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to solve a problem from leetcode, https://leetcode.com/problems/non-overlapping-intervals/

The solution to me seemed pretty simple.

1. sort the intervals by their starting points
2. use two indices. one for previous interval, one for current
3. initially set previous to 0 and current to 1
4. check if previous and current intervals overlap
5. if they do, find the longest interval and remove it
6. Here is how to remove an interval: if previous interval is longer then the current, then set previous index to the current index and move current index to the next position. If current interval is longer than a previous one then move current index to the next position
7. if intervals don't intersect then move set previous index to current index and move current index to the next position

Here is how I implemented it in Python

```
class Solution:
    def eraseOverlapIntervals(self, intervals: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        L = len(intervals)
        if L <= 1:
            return 0
        
        intervals.sort(key = lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))
        prev_idx = 0
        curr_idx = 1
        interval_cnt = 0
        while curr_idx < L:
            # intervals intersect
            if intervals[curr_idx][0] < intervals[prev_idx][1]:
                interval_cnt += 1
                prev_length = intervals[prev_idx][1] - intervals[prev_idx][0]
                curr_length = intervals[curr_idx][1] - intervals[curr_idx][0]
                # remove previous interval
                if prev_length >= curr_length:
                    prev_idx = curr_idx
                    curr_idx += 1
                else: # remove current interval
                    curr_idx += 1
            else: # intervals don't intersect
                prev_idx = curr_idx
                curr_idx += 1
               
        return interval_cnt
```

When I run my code on the following test case `[[-73,-26],[-65,-11],[-63,2],[-62,-49],[-52,31],[-40,-26],[-31,49],[30,47],[58,95],[66,98],[82,97],[95,99]]` I get an answer of 8. I also ran the test case manually (i.e. on paper) using the logic from the algorithm and got the answer of 8. However the correct answer is 7.

I did look at the solution for the problem but I can't make heads or tails of it.

Unfortunately I can't post leetcode solution because it is restricted content.

Comment: *"if they do, find the longest interval and remove it"* That doesn't sound right. Just because one them is longer doesn't make it the optimal choice for removal. E.g. the shorter one might overlap more others. See: `[0,9], [8, 11], [10, 12]` your algorithm removes 2, but only one is needed.

Comment: @user2390182 Do you mind explaining then how to come up with an optimal solution?

Comment: Comparing interval lengths is most certainly wrong in this application. Lengths are irrelevant. Only relative order of interval ends is meaningful.

Comment: BTW, that image you have there is from restricted content behind leetcode's premium paywall. I am not sure they like that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

```
class Solution:
    def eraseOverlapIntervals(self, intervals: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        intervals.sort()
        result = 0
        
        (_, p_end), *intervals = intervals
        for c_start, c_end in intervals:
            if c_start < p_end: # overlap!
                result += 1
                p_end = min(c_end, p_end)
            else:
                p_end = c_end
        
        return result
```

1. sort the intervals
2. keep track of the previous interval end `p_end`
3. for every current interval `c_start, c_end`

   a. if overlap with previous interval (`c_start < p_end`)

   1. increment removal count (one of them has to go!)
   2. set the end of previous interval to the smaller end! (remove the interval that ends later, leaving more space for later intervals)

   b. if no overlap

   1. set previous end to current end

Thinking about it, it is even sufficient to sort the intervals by their end. Then we never have to update the `p_end` in case of an overlap:

```
class Solution:
    def eraseOverlapIntervals(self, intervals: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        intervals.sort(key=itemgetter(1))
        result = 0
        (_, p_end), *intervals = intervals
        for c_start, c_end in intervals:
            if c_start < p_end: # overlap!
                result += 1  # no p_end update needed bcs of the sort!
            else:
                p_end = c_end
        return result
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining the logic behind the solution?

Comment: Added the logic steps.